# ofstream variable cannot appear in OpenMP firstprivate?

Tags: c++, openmp, ofstream

code

```
ofstream myfile("file_path");
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) schedule(dynamic) firstprivate(myfile) private(i)
for(i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    myfile<<omp_get_thread_num()+100<<endl;
}
```

but the compiler show me the error:

> error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ofstream<_CharT,
>   _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]’
>
> /usr/include/c++/5/fstream:723:7: note: declared here
>          basic_ofstream(const basic_ofstream&) = delete;
>
> error: ‘myfile’ not specified in enclosing parallel

Comment: You can't copy streams.

Answer (score 3):

`firstprivate` works by making a thread-private *copy* of the value. This does not work with streams, because you cannot copy them. You cannot safely write to a file just by having multiple streams of it open. There are basically two options:

- Have a **shared stream**, protect all threaded access to it with `#pragma omp critical`.

  ```
  ofstream myfile("file_path");
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
      #pragma omp critical
      myfile << (omp_get_thread_num()+100) << endl;
  }
  ```
- Open one stream for each thread on a **different file**.

  ```
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
      ofstream myfile(std::string("file_path.") + std::to_string(omp_get_thread_num()));
      #pragma omp for
      for (int i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
          myfile << (omp_get_thread_num()+100) << endl;
      }
  }
  ```